# How can I override a broken Haskell package in nix?

Tags: nixos, nix, haskell

I use NixOS, and I'm trying to set up a Nix Haskell environment for my Haskell project. I have [this Haskell package](https://github.com/open-editions/open-editions.org/blob/master/open-editions.nix) written in Nix that I'm trying to get working via `nix-shell`, but the dependent Haskell package Clay [won't build, as described in this bug report I just opened](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/54958). How can I override this package with a different (older or newer, I guess it doesn't matter) version of this Haskell package that works?

Comment: This might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56414329/how-do-i-override-a-haskell-package-with-a-git-local-package-with-nix-when-usi/56416694#56416694

Answer (score 3):

Not completely relevant, however I needed to modify an existing package that failed to build. I ended up with:

```
nixpkgs.config.packageOverrides = pkgs: {
    haskellPackages = pkgs.haskellPackages.override {
      overrides = hsSelf: hsSuper: {
        greenclip  = pkgs.haskell.lib.overrideCabal hsSuper.greenclip  (oa: {
          version = "3.1.1";
          sha256 = "1axh1q7kcvcnhn4rl704i4gcix5yn5v0sb3bdgjk4vgkd7fv8chw";
          executablePkgconfigDepends = oa.executablePkgconfigDepends ++ [pkgs.xorg.libXdmcp];
        });

        wordexp  = pkgs.haskell.lib.overrideCabal hsSuper.wordexp  (oa: {
          version = "0.2.2";
          sha256 = "1mbcrq89jz0dcibw66w0jdy4f4bfpx4zwjfs98rm3jjgdikwdzb4";
        });
      };
    };
  };
```

The above went in my configuration.nix

Answer (score 0):

For others looking, you can use `override` on the `haskellPackages` and provide an overlay in the `overrides` attribute, this will create your own version of the package set containing the overridden packages.

Example, removing version constraints on `beam-core` package and disabling tests on `beam-postgres` package.

```
myHaskellPackages = nixpkgs.haskellPackages.override {
    overrides = hself: hsuper: {
      # Can add/override packages here
      beam-core = nixpkgs.haskell.lib.doJailbreak hsuper.beam-core;
      beam-postgres = nixpkgs.haskell.lib.dontCheck hsuper.beam-postgres;
    };
  };
```

Then you use that modified package set to build your project:

```
myHaskellPackages.callCabal2nix "my-project" ./. { }
```

It's possible to build a derivation for a specific version of the package with `nixpkgs.haskellPackages.callHackage` as long as it exists on Hackage, or use `callCabal2nix` on a modified local repo, or `fetchFromGitHub` and alike to refer to a remote repo.

More details on fixing broken Haskell packages can be found [here](https://gutier.io/post/development-fixing-broken-haskell-packages-nixpkgs/), and tips in general about Haskell development with Nix [here](https://discourse.nixos.org/t/nix-haskell-development-2020/6170), you'll find there an example on how to override dependencies of a dependency.